# Dynamically adding a view with angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a dashboard in my angular app where ui-router opens several views by default. It basically follows the pattern of [this tutorial](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). I want to expand on this by allowing the user to open other views during runtime.

I've attached an image of what I require. A button the user can click to attach a new view to the current state. I think the $view module should allow me to do this but I'm unable to find any good documentation or examples online.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/8C5Lus8njmf1skfcrNP5) a plunker showing my current attempt. The main piece of code is:

```
$view.load("list@dashboard.main", {
  template: '<div class="view">this is the list section</div>'
});
```

Can someone let me know if there's a way of achieving this functionality, either with ui-router or some other module?

[image: addition of new view following user input]

Comment: This is an article worth reading [Dynamically Loading Controllers and Views](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm not sure it solves my issue. I can load and define a state during runtime but this will obviously need to be done before the view is rendered to the user. My question comes down to whether a state can be altered (by adding a new view) after it has been defined.

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve? I modified your [plunk code](http://plnkr.co/edit/SvY1kJZPe1gzJh31tvi6?p=info)